# Fuzzy prefix query with Whoosh

Tags: python, whoosh

I'm trying to implement a prefix fuzzy query with Whoosh - autocomplete-style search that allows typos. For example, I would like the following queries to match the document "hello world":

- "hello wo" (prefix search)
- "hellp" (fuzzy search, distance 1 to hello)
- "hello wir" (fuzzy prefix search, wir has distance 1 to a prefix of world)

I looked at the Whoosh query modules [FuzzyTerm](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/query.html#whoosh.query.FuzzyTerm) and [Prefix](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/query.html#whoosh.query.Prefix), but they seem to be separate. One could FuzzyTerm | Prefix, which would handle case 1 and 2, but not 3 - misspelling of a prefix. What's the solution here?